# How would I do this with $.get?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li class="catalog-list-item" data-icon="false">
    <a href="/items/170893265">
```

How would I use console.log to log the href `/items/IDHERE` (`IDHERE` = 170893265) by using catalog-list-item?

```
$.get("http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/CatalogSearch?startRow=0&keyword=&filter=Collectibles",
function(Data) {
    var test = $(Data).find('.catalog-list-item')
    var itemID = test.attr("href");
    console.log(itemID);
});
```

And that won't work for me (the test part does work, not the itemID part though.)

Answer (score 1):

You left out the `a` tag, which is the one you're targeting -- the one that has the **href** attribute you're looking for:

```
  var test = $(Data).find('a'); //<<<<-------
  var itemID = test.attr("href");
  console.log(itemID);
```

To get just the `id` use:

```
 var itemID = test.attr("href").split('/').pop();
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, $.get("http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/CatalogSearch?startRow=0&keyword=&filter=Collectibles", function(Data){
      var test = $(Data).find('.catalog-list-item a')
      var itemID = test.attr("href");
      console.log(itemID);
   });

Comment: Are you doing this from the roblox domain? I cannot reproduce due to same origin policy.

Comment: What is the result of console.log( Data )?

Answer (score 1):

If

```
<li class="catalog-list-item" data-icon="false">
    <a href="/items/170893265">
```

is the full response, then `li.catalog-list-item` will be the selected element in `$(Data)`. I.e. `$(Data).find('.catalog-list-item')` would try to find a `.catalog-list-item` element inside a `.catalog-list-item` element, which doesn't work.

You can [**`.filter`**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the selection and then search for the `a` element(s):

```
var test = $(Data).filter('.catalog-list-item').find('a');
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! One last question, how would I make it only log the numbers after / ?

Comment: You can either use a regular expression to extract the digits or remove non-digits, or you can split the string on `/` and get the last element.

Comment: `itemID.split('/')[2]` or `var arr = "/items/170893265".split('/'); arr[arr.length-1]` if its not always same pathing but still the last in the string

Answer (score 0):

you realize the `href` attribute isn't in the `li` tag. I suggest you do this

```
var test = $(Data).find('.catalog-list-item')
var itemID = test.find('a').attr("href")
console.log(itemID)
```